# iOS change button text to bold when highlighted or selected

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uibutton

I need to set title to bold when it is highlighted or selected

this is the code i use to generate button programmatically:

```
    UIButton *pagerButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [pagerButton setFrame:CGRectMake(offsetX, 10, 30, 30)];

    [pagerButton setTitle:pageNumber forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [pagerButton setTitleColor:[UIColor purpleColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

i can't find any property to set title's font or change it to bold forState:UIControlStateHighlighted

Comment: Try using `NSAttributedString` (with `setAttributedTitle:forState:`)?

Comment: Take a look at the UIButton class reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html

Answer (score 2):

Apart from color and shadow you would have to handle this situation in your own code. However bolding the text could also be done with attributed text, so you can use `setAttributedTitle:forState:`.

Answer (score 0):

When You click on The button then call the below method in your button click event

```
-(void)setButton:(UIButton *)button title:(NSString *)title fontSize:(CGFloat)fontSize
{
    [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Impact" fontSize]];
}
```

Comment: Please DON'T use uppercase variable names.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you can get to notify the changed state of the button.. I'm sure there is a way..

But you can set the button text to bold this way ----->

```
button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
```

It will set the font bold and you can also set the size...

However if you are using custom font, then you will need to get the bold style font of that family....
Hope it helped..